# Can Google see all my registered domains if I verify site ownership in Google Webmaster Tools using my GoDaddy account?

Tags: google, google-search-console, godaddy

When setting up Google Webmaster Tools, you have the choice to verify ownership of this domain by signing in with GoDaddy.

If you do this Google will confirm that you own the domain on GoDaddy.

My question is, will Google also see the full list of /other/ domains you own on GoDaddy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*No, because:*

- You are allowing GoDaddy to access your Google account.
- You are not allowing Google to access your GoDaddy account.

If you take a look at the picture below, then you can clearly see that it is a standard APP request for GoDaddy to access your Google Account. You can only add the domains that you click 'add' therefore the others will not be detected.

[image: GoDaddy Google Search Console]

If you're afraid of Google detecting interlinking of sites or another thing that is not considered whitehat then I will say there has been little to no evidence to support that Google uses that type of data to catch people out.

Often you have businesses having hundreds or even thousands of sites added to Google Search Console as they administrate it on behalf of their customer, to factor that in would be unfair guilt by association.

Google's Algorithm doesn't need the information in Google Search Console (AKA webmaster tools), its algorithm is far superior and can detect link schemes without.